# How to implement Edge computing using WSO2

Tags: wso2, analytics

I am currently running WSO2 Analytics on a windows server but I want implement the analysing part somehow that a client can connect to the server and do some processing like visualization on its own rather than all processing being done on the server. Is this something possible on WSO2 platform?
Thanks

Comment: The analyzed data (e.g. statistics) are already in the default SQL database. So in theory - you can create a client or service which reads the data from the database and displays them its own way..

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I'm thinking about using Oracle distributed database or something similar but now it leaves me with the question as how to change the default SQL so that the analysed data will be stored in a predetermined database. The second and I think the most challenging part for me is that how the client uses the information from the database? Do I need to install a component on the client or does the WSO2 provides a functionality for that?

Comment: Or maybe an API will do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup database you want ( see the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Product+Administration#ProductAdministration-Changingthedefaultdatabase) ). For production usage I woudn't even recomment using the bundled H2 database. WSO2 analytics supports number of databases by default, I believe Oracle is one of them.

As stated in the comments - you can create a client or service which reads the data from the database and displays them its own way.

> most challenging part for me is that how the client uses the information from the database?

This is already on your own (outside scope of this question). You've asked if your client can access the analytics (result) data - yes you can. How to do that is up to you. (depending what the client is, ..)

For example at our client they are building data APIs which are directly consumable by different frontend libraries creating nicer charts and reports.